# SQL command not properly ended error when implementing recursion

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
WITH TBL AS
(
   SELECT * FROM OUTPUT WHERE PRODUCT_ID = 5
   UNION ALL
   SELECT O.PRODUCT_ID,O.PRODUCT_NAME,O.PARENT_ID,O.PARENT_PRODUCT_NAME 
   FROM OUTPUT O
   JOIN TBL T1 ON O.PRODUCT_ID = T1.PARENT_ID
)
SELECT * FROM TBL
WHERE PRODUCT_ID <> 5
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 1000);
```

When I run the above code, I get the error statement "SQL command not properly ended". Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine.  [Here](http://rextester.com/EJU90411) is an example in RexTester of pretty much exactly the same query.

If you are getting an error, then perhaps you have code before this code.  That will cause the error.  The use of the semicolon prevents a problem with later code.

First, the recursion clause should explicitly list the columns.  Don't ever use `select *` and `select <column list>` and expect the two to match.  So list the columns:

```
WITH TBL AS (
      SELECT O.PRODUCT_ID, O.PRODUCT_NAME, O.PARENT_ID, O.PARENT_PRODUCT_NAME
      FROM OUTPUT O
      WHERE PRODUCT_ID = 5
      UNION ALL
      SELECT O.PRODUCT_ID, O.PRODUCT_NAME, O.PARENT_ID, O.PARENT_PRODUCT_NAME 
      FROM OUTPUT O JOIN
           TBL T1
           ON O.PRODUCT_ID = T1.PARENT_ID
     )
```

Second, you should not have `PARENT_PRODUCT_NAME` in your name.  You have `PARENT_ID`.  Use that to look up the name.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Microsoft T-SQL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql):

> When a CTE is used in a statement that is part of a batch, the statement before it must be followed by a semicolon.

Add an semicolon (`;`) after your previous statement / before your `WITH`. It might be a good practice to always prepend a `WITH`statement with a semicolon.

Answer (score -1):

CTE definition requires previous statements to end to be compiled correctly. So your code should be like

```
; --you were missing this
WITH TBL AS
(
   SELECT * FROM OUTPUT WHERE PRODUCT_ID = 5
   UNION ALL
   SELECT O.PRODUCT_ID,O.PRODUCT_NAME,O.PARENT_ID,O.PARENT_PRODUCT_NAME 
   FROM OUTPUT O
   JOIN TBL T1 ON O.PRODUCT_ID = T1.PARENT_ID
)
SELECT * FROM TBL
WHERE PRODUCT_ID <> 5
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 1000);
```